# How to write a Gmail extension that will intercept and process outgoing emails?

Tags: email, gmail-api, gmail-imap, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I would like to write a gmail extension that can intercept outgoing emails and modify / squash them if needed. (My exact purpose is data-leak-prevention, but I'd like to keep this question general). Ideally, a domain admin would be able to install it on all email accounts for that domain, but I'll take a solution that works on a per account basis for now, if I can get one.

If I understand correctly, a contextual gadget isn't right, since (among other reasons) it can't intercept email not sent via logging into Gmail via a browser (say, sending email from my account using my iOS client).

The gmail-api (or IMAP/POP) will allow me to access the user's inbox, but not be in-path for outgoing emails.

Is this even possible to do with gmail?

Comment: There may be a software solution that has a send delay. That is what I'm guessing you want.

Comment: Hi Evan. No, what I'm looking for is a solution whereby gmail will run my code on any email that is being sent from a gmail account, and let me manipulate / discard the attempted send. A delay is not really necessary for achieving this purpose, and certainly not sufficient. If the question is not clear, please let me know and I'll rewrite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can route ALL outgoing mail to another mail server using outbound gateway setting or outgoing mail that matches certain criteria using content compliance rules.

OB Gateway: https://support.google.com/a/answer/178333?hl=en

Content Compliance: https://support.google.com/a/answer/1346934?hl=en